# Codebuild aws command not found when ran?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-codebuild

I'm trying to get a simple docker app to build using AWS **codebuild**, but I am coming across an error where the **aws** command is not found:

```
[Container] 2016/12/10 04:29:17 Build started on Sat Dec 10 04:29:17 UTC 2016
[Container] 2016/12/10 04:29:17 Running command echo Building the Docker image...
[Container] 2016/12/10 04:29:17 Building the Docker image...
[Container] 2016/12/10 04:29:17 Running command docker build -t aws-test .
[Container] 2016/12/10 04:29:17 sh: 1: docker: not found
[Container] 2016/12/10 04:29:17 Command did not exit successfully docker build -t aws-test . exit status 127
[Container] 2016/12/10 04:29:17 Phase complete: BUILD Success: false
[Container] 2016/12/10 04:29:17 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: docker build -t aws-test .. Reason: exit status 127
```

I've got a super simple docker file which builds a simple express app:

```
FROM node:6.2.0

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 3000

CMD npm install && npm start
```

And I've got a super simple **buildspec.yml** which is suppose to build the docker container and push it to the **aws** registry:

```
version: 0.1

phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
      - $(aws ecr get-login --region us-west-2)
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo Building the Docker image...          
      - docker build -t <CONTAINER_NAME> .
      - docker tag <CONTAINER_NAME>:latest <ID>.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/<CONTAINER_NAME>:latest
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
      - echo Pushing the Docker image...
      - docker push <ID>.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/<CONTAINER_NAME>:latest
```

However once ran, it throws the error posted above ^^ I'm not sure why the **aws** cli utils aren't found? This guide here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-docker.html

Suggests I don't need to do anything to setup the **aws** cli utils anywhere?

Also one other thing I noticed, I removed **$(aws ecr get-login --region us-west-2)** step from the buildspec file, built it again and it then said that the docker command was not found?! Have I missed a step somewhere (I don't think I have).

Comment: What is the image you're using as the project environment?  Are you using one of the CodeBuild managed environments?

Comment: Thank you very much @ClareLiguori I was a bit confused and used the wrong env container. You can create an answer and I'll accept it if you like?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So it turned out I was using the wrong environment. Here is what I'm using now:

[image: Now]

I was trying to specify my own docker image, which was ultimately not setup with any of the AWS cli utils!

Thanks to **@Clare Liguori** for tipping me off!

Comment: Additionally, you must now specify the Runtime "Docker", which is below the scrolling fold in that dropdown. This isn't explicitly stated in any of the documentation, and it's easy to miss in the non-alphabetized dropdown list below the fold.

Comment: Privileged  checkbox must be ON